# I'm starting out with python and keep getting a problem with indents

Tags: python, python-3.5

This is the entire code, I've highlighted the main part of the problem in bold. Extra info, I'm on version 3.5.9, I'm just using IDLE, not IDLEx as it does not work.

```
import time
import sys

def play_game_yn (): #asks if wants to play game
time.sleep (1.5)
play_game=input ('Do you want to play a game? (y/n)')

    if play_game=='Y':
        play_yes ()
    elif play_game=='y':
        play_yes ()
    **elif play_game=='N':
    play_game_sure=input ("Are you sure you don't want to play? (y/n)") #asks if sure don't want play
        if play_game_sure=='Y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='N':
            play_yes ()
        elif play_game_sure=='n':
            play_yes ()
        else:
            print ("Please enter 'y'or'n'") 
            time.sleep (2)
            play_game_yn ()
    elif play_game=='N':
        play_game_sure=input ("Are you sure you don't want to play? (y/n)") #asks if sure don't want play
        if play_game_sure=='Y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='N':
            play_yes ()
        elif play_game_sure=='n':
            play_yes ()
        else:
            print ("Please enter 'y'or'n'") 
            time.sleep (2)
            play_game_yn ()**
    else:
        print ("Please enter 'y'or'n'") 
        time.sleep (2)
        play_game_yn ()


def play_yes(): #play yes
    print ("Woohoo,")
    time.sleep (0.5)
    game=input ("What game do you want to play?") #asks what game want play
    print ("Uhmm...")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ("Let me think...")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("Nope, doesn't ring any bells")
    time.sleep (0.75)
    print ("Sorry,", name + ", I have no clue how to play", game + "")
    time.sleep (5)
    sys.exit()

def play_no (): #play no
    print ('Awwh, it was fun while it lasted')
    time.sleep (1)
    print ('See ya around,',name + '')
    tine.sleep (2)
    sys.exit()

name=input ("Hey there, I'm SIRB, Super Intelligent Robot Boy, what's your name?") #intriduces sirb & ask name

if name=='harry':
    print ("hey, that's the same name as the person who made me :)")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ('Hello, ' + name + ', it is nice to meet you')
    play_game_yn ()
elif name=='Harry':
    print ("hey, that's the same name as the person who made me :)")
    time.sleep
    print ('Hello, ' + name + ', it is nice to meet you')
    play_game_yn ()
else:
    print ('Hello, ' + name + ', that is a nice name, nice to meet you')
    play_game_yn ()
```

ps, How do you get the vertical lines that show tabulation?
pps, Really sorry about how much code this is, I'm very new to python and made this account just for this problem

Comment: "It does not work" is not a description. [mcve]

Comment: Are `elif play_game=='N':` and `play_game_sure=input(...)` indented to the same level? If so, you need to indent the second line one more level.

Comment: `tine.sleep (2)` has a typo. Also, your spacing seems really inconsistent; I highly recommend using a free Python-centric IDE like PyCharm, which can really help make sure all the indentation is correct, and show syntax errors and such in realtime. Indentation is a core part of the flow of any Python program; you have to know exactly how it works or else you're going to have a very hard time. For example, you can't just randomly indent some code for no reason - that'd immediately throw a syntax error. And, the indentation of every `elif` has to exactly match up to an `if`.

Comment: *How do you get the vertical lines that show tabulation?* In IDLE, you can't. It would have difficulty with lining things up when some lines have `>>>` prompts and others don't. IDLE isn't for writing long programs that you need indentation guides for. Use PyCharm (Community Edition is free) or Notepad++ (free).

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the indentations and one more thing there was a value missing in line 52 for time.sleep which i gave a value of 2 please change it as per your requirement.

```
import time
import sys

def play_game_yn (): #asks if wants to play game
    time.sleep (1.5)
    play_game=input ('Do you want to play a game? (y/n)')

    if play_game=='Y':
        play_yes ()
    elif play_game=='y':
        play_yes ()
    elif play_game=='N':
        play_game_sure=input ("Are you sure you don't want to play? (y/n)") #asks if sure don't want play
        if play_game_sure=='Y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='N':
            play_yes ()
        elif play_game_sure=='n':
            play_yes ()
        else:
            print ("Please enter 'y'or'n'")
            time.sleep (2)
            play_game_yn ()

    elif play_game=='N':
        play_game_sure=input ("Are you sure you don't want to play? (y/n)") #asks if sure don't want play
        if play_game_sure=='Y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='y':
            play_no ()
        elif play_game_sure=='N':
            play_yes ()
        elif play_game_sure=='n':
            play_yes ()
        else:
            print ("Please enter 'y'or'n'")
            time.sleep (2)
            play_game_yn ()
    else:
        print ("Please enter 'y'or'n'")
        time.sleep (2)
        play_game_yn ()


def play_yes(): #play yes
    print ("Woohoo,")
    time.sleep (0.5)
    game=input ("What game do you want to play?") #asks what game want play
    print ("Uhmm...")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ("Let me think...")
    time.sleep (1)
    print ("Nope, doesn't ring any bells")
    time.sleep (0.75)
    print ("Sorry,", name + ", I have no clue how to play", game + "")
    time.sleep (5)
    sys.exit()

def play_no (): #play no
    print ('Awwh, it was fun while it lasted')
    time.sleep (1)
    print ('See ya around,',name + '')
    time.sleep (2)
    sys.exit()

name=input ("Hey there, I'm SIRB, Super Intelligent Robot Boy, what's your name?") #intriduces sirb & ask name

if name=='harry':
    print ("hey, that's the same name as the person who made me :)")
    time.sleep (2)
    print ('Hello, ' + name + ', it is nice to meet you')
    play_game_yn ()
elif name=='Harry':
    print ("hey, that's the same name as the person who made me :)")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('Hello, ' + name + ', it is nice to meet you')
    play_game_yn ()
else:
    print ('Hello, ' + name + ', that is a nice name, nice to meet you')
    play_game_yn ()
```